# JavaScript Calculo Estranho

Tags: javascript, node.js, matemática

Estou tentando executar o seguinte calculo no JavaScript, `78.98 * 10` e o resultado retornado sempre é `789.8000000000001` minha pergunta é de onde veio esse `0.0000000000001`?

Tentei em diversas calculadoras, e esse `0.0000000000001` não deveria estar ai. Fiz testes inclusive em outras linguagens de programação.

Minha pergunta é, tem alguma explicação lógica para isso? Caso seja um erro no motor do JavaScript onde eu notifico?

Obrigado.

Comment: Muitos valores de virgula flutuante não tem representação exata em binario. Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) e [aqui](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/)

Comment: Estava olhando no SOP em inglês e me mandaram esse site: http://0.30000000000000004.com/